# AES_CCM_Encrypt: как запустить готовый агоритм

Tags: c#, .net, шифрование

Здравствуйте! Помогите, пожалуйста, заюзать это [C#. Криптографические алгоритмы. AES-256](http://www.vr-online.ru/content/c-kriptograficheskie-algoritmy-aes-256-3297). 
Не могу понять как правильно разбить файл на куски и зашифровать/расшифровать. Нужно заюзать метод `AES_CCM_Encrypt`. Постоянно часть файла расшифровывается не верно. (Родной `AES` из `.NET` не предлагать).

Comment: ссылка битая.

Comment: Исправил ссылку.